# Autocomplete that fills textbox as well as dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete

I need autocomplete textboxes that have the textbox filled as you type along with filling the dropdown, like the browser addressbar:

[image]

[image]

All you have to do is hit tab for the textbox to be filled in and go to the next page control. I've got the autocomplete working fine, I just need to have the textbox filled. I don't know where to start.

Edit: I put the autocomplete code on JSFiddle, but it won't fill the dropdown since the web method is hosted outside the intranet that it sits on. There is no access to the database. I don't know if this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelmeow/noabLz7k/

The web method:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetScopes(ByVal sLookUP As String) As String()
    Dim scopes As New List(Of String)()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT JobScopeDesc, JobScopeID FROM view_JobScopeCode where JobScopeDesc like '%' + @SearchText + '%' ORDER BY JobScopeDesc"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", sLookUP)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    scopes.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr("JobScopeDesc").ToString(), sdr("JobscopeID")))
                End While
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
        Return scopes.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Please show existing code.

Comment: @DevlshOne I don't even know where to start. Do you want my autocomplete code?

Comment: Have you ever used JSFiddle? You can post a whole page's worth of code there for all to see and edit. That would be the best way to proceed.

Comment: @DevlshOne No, I haven't. I have code in a .asmx file and code in the aspx file, how would I do this? And it's a pretty big page...

Comment: In your browser, "View Source", then copy/paste the appropriate parts onto the JSFiddle site. You'll need to create an account there but it will come in handy if you ever need assistance again.

Comment: @DevlshOne Got it. Now where do I put the web method code? That's what's driving the autocomplete.

Comment: On the left side of the JSFiddle page, there is a place for "External Resources". Include it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72947/discussion-between-pixelmeow-and-devlshone).